# Use a library created in Android Studio in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-studio, sdk

I create a new library with Android Studio. And now I want to use it with Eclipse (because some people use Eclipse for them applications.).

I have tested my jar file from the library in a android project and it's running fine.
But when I want to use it with Eclipse I have some errors :

> 03-26 14:25:59.442: W/System.err(31062):  at
>   com.mylib.MyLib.access$000(MyLib.java:24)
>
> 03-26 14:25:59.442: W/System.err(31062):  at
>   com.mylib.MyLib$2.run(MyLib.java:114)

I don't understand why I don't have no problem with Android Studio and these ones with Eclipse?

Comment: Have you checked out the code at lines 24 and lines 114 in MyLib.java? Perhaps you are attempting to access something that your Eclipse environment does not yet support.

Comment: line 24 is the constructor of mylib and 
line 114 is a private set of mylib

Comment: Darn, ok. Not sure what it could be then. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of search, I have found an error in the console log :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your
>   app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following
>   declaration within the  element:

I have followed the indications and is working fine now.
Maybe the other problems are due to this one.

Thanks for the help.